# SQL Server 2016 connection using sqlalchemy and pyodbc returns no tables

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm able to connect to the SQL server using the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=serv;"
                                 "DATABASE=db1;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

It is a company server and we have a number of databases, for instance db1, db2, etc.
The problem is, when I query table names from a database, using this:

```
inspector = sa.inspect(engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names())
```

It does not work in all cases, i.e. it returns table names for db1 but returns an empty list for db2 although there are tables in that database.

I'm not able to understand this behavior, it shows no error, meaning a successful connection, so why it is not able to show the table names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, for databases where I'm not able to retrieve any table, the default schema (`inspector.default_schema_name`) is set to my Windows username instead of dbo. That's why it is not able to find any table.

Passing the required schema as an argument solves the problem.

```
inspector = sa.inspect(engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names(schema='dbo'))
```

Although this solves the problem, I still don't know the reason as to why for some databases the default schema is set to dbo and for others my Windows username.